# What is work of buddhi(intelligence)?

Tags: scripture, meaning, buddhi

For E.g In scriptures it is said that buddhi(intelligence) makes decision(निस्चय).But I think it must have broader meaning.

What are the other characteristics of buddhi(intelligence)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buddhi is one of the 17 components that form the Linga Deha/Sukshma Sarira (subtle body).

> My subtle body (Linga Deha) arises from the union of the five
> Jñânendriyas, the five Karmendriyas (organs of action), the five
> Pranas and the mind and Buddhi, these seventeen elements. And the
> Prakriti that resides there is divided into two parts; one is pure
> (Suddha Sattva) Mâyâ and the other is the impure Mâyâ or Avidyâ united
> with the Gunas. By Mâyâ is meant She, who, without concealing Her
> refugees, protects them. When the Supreme Self is reflected on this
> S'uddha Sattva, Mâyâ, He is called Îs'vara.
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam 7.32**

If we think the body as a chariot then Buddhi (intellect) has been compared to the charioteer in the scriptures.

> That is Brahma and My Nature, too. This is the Goal of "Not this, Not
> this" the Vedânta words. This Self is not born nor It dies. It does
> not live also, being born. (But it remains constant, though It is not
> born). This Self is unborn, eternal, everlasting, ancient. It is not
> killed, when the body is killed. If one wants to kill it or thinks It
> as slain, both of them do not know; this does not kill nor is it
> killed. This Âtman, subtler than the subtlest, and greater than the
> greatest, resides within the cave (the Buddhi) of the Jîvas. He whose
> heart is purified and who is free from Sankalpa and Vikalpa (doubt and
> mental phenomena), knows It and Its glory and is free from sorrows and
> troubles. **Know this Âtman and Buddhi as the charioteer, this body as
> the chariot, and the mind as the reins. The senses and their organs
> are the horses and the objects of enjoyments are their aims.** The
> sages declare that the Âtman united with mind and organs of senses
> enjoys the objects. He who is nondiscriminating, unmindful, and always
> impure, does not realise his Âtman; rather he is bound in this world.
> He who is discriminating, mindful, and always pure reaches the Goal,
> realises the Highest Self; and he is not fallen again from That.
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam 7.34**

Same thing is mentioned in the [[Katha Upanishad 1.3.3](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/katha-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145206.html)][1](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/katha-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145206.html):

> आत्मानँ रथितं विद्धि शरीरँ रथमेव तु ।
> बुद्धिं तु सारथिं विद्धि मनः प्रग्रहमेव च ॥ ३ ॥
>
> ātmānam̐ rathitaṃ viddhi śarīram̐ rathameva tu |
> buddhiṃ tu sārathiṃ viddhi manaḥ pragrahameva ca || 3 ||
>
> 3. Know the atman as the lord of the chariot, the body as only the chariot, know also intelligence as the driver; know the minds as the
>    reins.

From this analogy it should clear what is the role of Buddhi. Buddhi has complete control over both the mind and the body.